# What edge connector for prototype board?

Tags: connector, prototyping, motherboard

For personal hobby projects I'm using prototype boards like this (2.54 mm pitch):

[image]

I connect them using wires, which is a mess. I want to use a backplane with female edge connectors, for a solution like this:

[image]

Making a PCB is out of question, mostly because I keep adding components to my projects to add further functionalities.

After searching, the only female edge connector I found was 3.96mm pitch ones, that seems to be incompatible with prototype boards.

I'm looking for a solution, better if it accepts the prototype board as is (without a male connector). Cost is not a big factor.

Any sugestion is welcome.

**Edit**

Durability is not an issue; I keep producing new versions every 12 to 18 months. Cheap components, hardware is totally disposable (I don't even bother recycling them).

Comment: http://canada.newark.com/samtec/tms-133-01-g-s-ra/header-1-27mm-though-hole-right/dp/77P1248?mckv=sPAHdDGZa_dc|pcrid|59878609972|plid||kword||match||slid||product|77P1248|&gross_price=true&CATCI=pla-294680686006&CAAGID=23354969332&CMP=KNC-GCA-GEN-SHOPPING-77P1248&CAGPSPN=pla&gclid=CjwKCAjwlIvXBRBjEiwATWAQIiYiZ586pPVvGeaTmq0kn4bAXmJIwaLiNCZ2bGMpcxcCcR45_UW6CRoCmfYQAvD_BwE&CAWELAID=120185770000628802

Comment: That backplane doesn't use edge connectors.

Comment: *"Making a PCB is out of question, mostly because I keep adding components to my projects to add further functionalities."* Well, you know you could actually design your own PCB that includes a prototyping area (in addition to edge contacts). Just sayin'...

Comment: Ignacio's comment on my answer brings something up: is the 3.96 mm pitch between adjacent pins or between rows?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. That's the best picture I found to ilustrate the whole idea. Please, just think of it like edge connectors.

Comment: The companies that make Veroboard also make versions with edge-card connectors. [For example](https://www.vectorelect.com/4112-5.html)

Comment: You can find ISA or PCI protoboards here and there, if you're looking for a common edge format (although I wouldn't actually plug them into a generic ISA/PCI backplane/motherboard unless it was actually a card of that type).

Comment: if you would use the "PCBs" that have a breadboard-like footprint you can reduce the number of wires on your board, often by 50% in my experience. i find ribbon cables handy for interconnects, though not as sexy as edge connectors they work well and provide dupont cable-compat test points even when not hooked together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not averse to cutting down the PCB and chamfering the raw edges slightly* then something like an ordinary [PCB edge connector](http://uk.farnell.com/amp-te-connectivity/5-5530843-0/connector-card-edge-rcpt-20pos/dp/2396188) could work with ordinary Veroboard as the backplane PCB for single-sided daughter boards.

* <sub>Remember it's fibreglass so don't get the little shards on your skin or in your lungs if you can avoid it.</sub>

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams From counting the pixels in the OP's photo I determined that the 2.54 mm pitch of the example connector would be just right. And in the other direction... well, it's Veroboard so it can be persuaded.

Comment: Never mind, I misread the row-to-row spacing as the pitch.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do it like in the picture you posted?

Your prototype board already has the holes to fit [0.1" right angle male headers](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=SNB&biw=1277&bih=746&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=q3LjWsPMMpGXkwX8wKAo&q=0.1%22%20%20right%20angle%20header&oq=0.1%22%20%20right%20angle%20header&gs_l=psy-ab.3...92090.96081.0.96523.18.17.0.0.0.0.315.2112.0j8j3j1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..10.0.0....0.0WoNQego5yU#imgrc=kEcM5igcv6EKHM:) on the edges, and you can use [strip board](https://www.google.fr/search?q=strip%20board&safe=off&client=opera&hs=6PB&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK24zykdvaAhWla5oKHSHUBnkQ_AUICigB&biw=1277&bih=746) as the "backplane" with [female 0.1" connectors](https://www.google.fr/search?safe=off&client=opera&hs=pjq&biw=1277&bih=746&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=GHPjWrrUNcKxkwX8kbuYAw&q=0.1%22%20%20female%20header&oq=0.1%22%20%20female%20header&gs_l=psy-ab.3...26639.27218.0.27338.6.5.0.0.0.0.187.310.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0....0.wLewk3tQP-c#imgrc=UddYV7XAzmFzIM:).

You can get all of this on aliexpress for ridiculously low prices (like $1 = 500 pins worth of headers).

Using a card edge connector is just going to be more cumbersome and more expensive. Also the fingers on your protoboard are too short, they don't reach the edge, once you solder something into the holes they'll be full of solder, and you'll need to cut the board... or you can use a $0.05 pin header!

Comment: They looks rather flimsy to me. I want something heavy duty, able to withstand many insertions/extractions. (I already have those for my Arduino projects).

Comment: @CandidMoe You should add the durability requirement to the question ;)

Comment: If you want Card edge connectors to withstand "lots" of insertions, you need gold plated fingers with enough gold thickness... immersion gold PCB finish is very thin, it protects against oxidation, not mechanical wear. Also 18 or 35µm copper plating is less durable than solid metal pin...

Comment: @CandidMoe I think you'll find that pin headers are quite durable. However you might not want to use them if your board needs to resist mechanical shock or vibration, as (especially the right angle ones) they can act like a spring.

Answer (score -2):

[**JST connectors**](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?k=jst&k=&pkeyword=jst&pv1790=26&FV=ffe0013a&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

This could be a little bit too advanced or too much but it is a good practice to start using them in your hobbies because most companies in the tech industry use them. Plus you will learn how to crimp, and for the size of the connector you are looking for the tool is really affordable; Amazon has it for around $22. I know the link I gave you is for 2.50 mm pitch but it should be able to work.

Comment: Delete the extra space between the ] ( of your hyperlink and it should hide the website.

Comment: I'm already using wires, both with JST connectors and male/header pin connectors. That makes a rat net of wires over the boards. Also, there is the risk of plugin things incorrectly. With a backplane, no such risk.